# AngularJS BooutstrapUI Typeahead with dynamic data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

I'd like to find the way to pass to the Angular UI typeahead dynamic data.

The problem is that when I've got the data the popup doesn't appear.

So, is there any method to open the typeahead popup or some way to use $apply in the angular controller?

Comment: are you wanting it for both user to type in and to pass values to input from script? Or just scenario mentioned with no user typing?

Comment: Show the non-working code?